# Getting stonewalled on computation of $2\times 2$ Hessian matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-spaces, partial-derivative

**The question:** Let $z \in R^N$, and let $f(z) = \log[1^T z] \in R$. I am told that the Hessian matrix of this function is the following:

$$
H = \frac{1}{1^Tz}\Big[ 1^Tz \mathrm{diag}(z) - zz^T  \Big]
$$

I am not sure how this was attained.

EDIT: This is the clip from my book. Here is the function:

[image]

...and here is the Hessian my books claims:

[image]

**What I tried:**

To keep things simple, I simply decided to do this 'by hand' for a 2x2 case. So first I write the function as $f(z_1,z_2) = \log(\frac{1}{z_1 + z_2})$. When I take the first and second partial derivatives, I will get $-\frac{1}{(z_1 + z_2)^2}$ for *all* (second order) partial combinations. So the Hessian will just be a matrix of that for all 4 of its entries.

I am not seeing how what I did for a simple $2 \times 2$ case corresponds to what the answer should be. Furthermore I would like to do the derivation using vector/matrix derivatives but not sure how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $z=(e^{x_1},e^{x_2},\cdots,e^{x_n})$

Since, you have $f:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $f$ is of the form $f(x)=\phi(g(x))$ where $g$ is of the form $g(x)=1^{T}z$, $\phi$ is of the form $\phi(x)=\log x$ you can use the formula $$\nabla f(x)=\phi'(g(x))\nabla g(x)$$ Since $\nabla g(x)=z$ (vector), you have $\frac{1}{1^Tz}z$ which has $i$ th component as $\displaystyle \frac{z_i}{1^Tz}=\frac{e^{x_i}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+\cdots+e^{x_n}}$. So, the $i,j$ th component of the Hessian is, $$H_{ij}(x)=\nabla_{ij}^2f(x)=
\left\{\begin{array}
--\frac{z_iz_j}{(1^Tz)^2} & ,i\ne j\\
\frac{z_i(1^Tz-z_i)}{(1^Tz)^2} & ,i=j
\end{array}
\right.\Rightarrow H(x)=\frac{1}{(1^Tz)^2}[(1^Tz)\mbox{diag}(z)-zz^T]
$$

Comment: I will put some pictures up from the book, because the book seems adamant. Give me 2 minutes.

Comment: I edited the question @Samrat, this is what the book says exactly.

Comment: @Spacey, I think the book is correct, (I think it is Boyd's book), the problem was that maybe you did not notice that $z=(e^{x_1},e^{x_2},\cdots,e^{x_n})$. I will rewrite the proof to see if it is correct.

Comment: Thanks Samrat, I did notice what $z$ is, but that should make no difference since in the computation of the Hessian he just works with $z$, never $x$. (Yes it is Boyd's book). :-)

Comment: Samrat I am confused by the beginning of your answer. Isnt $z_i = e^{x_i}$? Also why is the derivative of $\nabla g(x) = z$ the vector?

Comment: Last element should be $zz^T$ btw. Either way thanks that helped.

Comment: Oops! I'm editing it.